# AngularJS - How to stop ng-repeat when it reaches the last item on object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I ng-repeat a huge object and is working fast on chrome and opera. but on browsers like mozilla and IE, it is very very slow. I tried using pagination and it helped but i would want to display all the items on load instead of paginating them. So i came up with the idea if it is possible to stop ng-repeat from listening to the object after executing the last item on the object.

But it should not remove the html elements that it rendered.

And if the object was changed it should rerun the ng-repeat again and will stop on the last item.

From what i know about ng-repeat, it keeps on looping the object infinitely, so that could be the reason why IE and Mozilla is slow at loading them when the object is too large.

So is this possible to stop ng-repeat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your collection isn't changing at all, ngRepeat shouldn't be changing the DOM. You should profile carefully, to make sure the problem is what you think it is.

In the documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat),

> ngRepeat uses $watchCollection to detect changes in the collection. When a change happens, ngRepeat then makes the corresponding changes to the DOM:
>
> When an item is added, a new instance of the template is added to the DOM.
>
> When an item is removed, its template instance is removed from the DOM.
>
> When items are reordered, their respective templates are reordered in the DOM.

It isn't possible to prevent this, and `$watchCollection` (I believe) has to iterate through your collection to see if anything has been reordered.

It also doesn't look like it's possible to 'turn off' the watch while still using ngRepeat.

If you don't want to use `$watchCollection` as your mechanism for detecting changes, you might have to create your own dirty checking/trigger, and generate the DOM yourself.

Comment: i see. Well then if this is the case i can always run pagination by default if the browser is mozilla or IE and remove pagination if chrome or opera. thanks!

Comment: @VoltaireJohnSecondesBiton Did you actually profile what causes the slowdown in mozilla and IE? The actual iteration through your collection (unless there are thousands upon thousands of items) shouldn't cause too big a hit, unless your collection is constantly changing

Comment: it doesnt change constantly. but the object is too big for mozilla and IE to process. it usually hangs on load and takes about 2-3 minutes for it to load the entire object. however it hangs a lot after loading everything. paginating the list made it faster.